# How many random cards picks with replacement are required?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

> You pick 1 card from a standard deck of 52 cards. Then put it back in, and pick a card again. Then put it back in and pick a card. etc...
>
> How many times do you have to repeat in order to have a 90% chance of having picked (at least) 39 (75% of 52) different cards? [Or a deck of $k$ cards, a $P$ chance of picking at least $p$ x $k$ different numbers]
>
> **Alternatively (same math, but different visual)**: How many times do you have to roll a standard 6-sided die in order to have a 90% chance of having rolled (at least) 4 different numbers (66% of 6). [Or a $k$ sided die, $P$ chance of rolling at least $p$ x $k$ different numbers]

I'm at a complete loss as to how to figure out a formula (if one exists).  I was toying with this and the closest I can get to (through a decision tree) is where the amount of rolls "n" necessary are the solution to:

> $$\frac{((1/6)^{n+1}-1)*((2/6)^{n+1}-1)*((3/6)^{n+1}-1)}{((1/6)-1)*((2/6)-1)*((3/6)-1)}>0.90$$

But there are already many problems:
(a) I have no idea if that's even remotely close
(b) I came across this "solution" by intuition/toying with decision trees
(c) I have no idea how to solve it, and most important of all,
(d) It would be unwieldy to use for a deck of $k$ cards...

So what's the actual mathematical solution here?

Comment: A simulation came up with values of 8 throws for the dice (about 0.92), and 82 picks for the cards (about 0.9), for the given requirement.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I got for dice using a decision tree; 8 rolls for 0.92.  My formula at the top is so very wrong.  The big question now is:  Can a formula be figured out that will allow to calculate based on any variables?  Also how are you simulating?  Doing a decision tree for 8 rolls of a die took me forever; can't imagine doing that for a deck....!

Comment: Hi, I tried getting a formula, going wrong somewhere. I simulated in J, an array programming language. Here's my [simulation code](http://pastebin.com/HN7HjuZB).

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using exponential generating functions, and extract the $n^{th}$ coefficient to obtain an explicit formula.

For the simpler dice problem showing at least 4 distinct, the egf is:

$$
f(x)=(e^x-1)^4\, \binom{6}{4}+(e^x-1)^5\, \binom{6}{5}+(e^x-1)^6\, \binom{6}{6}
$$

From that, we need the $n^{th}$ coefficient, times $n!$ to get the number of possible permutations of dice rolled having at least 
4 distinct numbers.

The explicit formula for the probability is then:

$
\mathbb{P}_{\text{dice}}(n)=\dfrac{6^{n} - 20 \cdot 3^{n} + 45 \cdot 2^{n} - 36}{6^n}
$

We may verify with the simulation value in the comment:
$$
\mathbb{P}_{\text{dice}}(8)=\dfrac{21665}{23328}\approx 0.928712277091907
$$
Similarly, the egf for the cards showing up at least 39 distinct is:

$$
g(x)=(e^x-1)^{39}\, \binom{52}{39}+(e^x-1)^{40}\, \binom{52}{40}+(e^x-1)^{41}\, \binom{52}{41}+\cdots +(e^x-1)^{52}\, \binom{52}{52}
$$

This also yields a formula, a big one though.

$\displaystyle
\mathbb{P}_{\text{cards}}(n) = \left(52^{n} - 1768966344600 \cdot 38^{n} + 62739339688480 \cdot 37^{n} -\\
1088135422722075 \cdot 36^{n} + 12289529480155200 \cdot 35^{n} -\\
101559306120727000 \cdot 34^{n} + 654255740482999200 \cdot 33^{n} -\\
3418486244023670820 \cdot 32^{n} + 14883205416157478400 \cdot 31^{n} -\\
55050947306355218400 \cdot 30^{n} + 175524759527509392000 \cdot 29^{n} -\\
487812560853536518600 \cdot 28^{n} + 1192036512340278329088 \cdot 27^{n} -\\
2578925146890025231200 \cdot 26^{n} + 4966818801417826371200 \cdot 25^{n} -\\
8552557885094471430000 \cdot 24^{n} + 13212227353525252416000 \cdot 23^{n} -\\
18359490926669465336400 \cdot 22^{n} + 22992910837954169112000 \cdot 21^{n} -\\
25986779436646118215125 \cdot 20^{n} + 26525580286209753840000 \cdot 19^{n} -\\
24458145352137523026000 \cdot 18^{n} + 20365149599330835499200 \cdot 17^{n} -\\
15299575772224554447000 \cdot 16^{n} + 10355529547357630272000 \cdot 15^{n} -\\
6301884757438031580000 \cdot 14^{n} + 3438566862520033641600 \cdot 13^{n} -\\
1676301345478516400280 \cdot 12^{n} + 726851531914803859200 \cdot 11^{n} -\\
278750034773449439200 \cdot 10^{n} + 93885336491458512000 \cdot 9^{n} -\\
27525473653177609200 \cdot 8^{n} + 6945495860873489920 \cdot 7^{n} -\\
1486298366966813400 \cdot 6^{n} + 264486363173978400 \cdot 5^{n} -\\
38084739795272625 \cdot 4^{n} + 4263714309441600 \cdot 3^{n} - \\
348203335271064 \cdot 2^{n} + 18452746967200\right)/52^n
$

and

$$\mathbb{P}_{\text{cards}}(82)\approx 0.903730370831740$$

Update:

We may rewrite the formula in general form and get the probability for the values in the asked in the comment:

$\displaystyle a(k,m,n) = \binom{k}{m}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{m} (-1)^i \, \binom{m}{i}\cdot (m-i)^n$

$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}_{cards}(811)=\dfrac{1}{640^{811}}\sum_{m=450}^{640}a(640,m,811)\approx 0.901973726672271$

Comment: So in other words, there is no specific formula, and the formula that needs to be generated gets exponentially bigger?  So there's no way of calculating 90% chance of getting 450 different cards out of a 640-card deck?

Comment: Due to the nature of the problem, I don't think there is a simple formula. Though it's possible to rewrite it as a summation involving binomials. See my update to the answer.

Comment: can you add a sentence or two on how you got the formula for the egf, f(x)?

Comment: E.g. consider a n letter permutation from 4 characters, where at least each of them are to be present, the egf for that $(e^x-1)^4$, and those 4 characters are chosen from 6 available characters. Hence the $6 \choose 4$ part in that.