# In how many options can one cast 10 game cubes in different colors so that all the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6 will apear?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I study discrete and I missed some lessons. Can you help?

The problem:
We have 10 game cubes, each in a different color. The question is what is the number of options to throw all the 10 cubes and get all the digits from 1 to 6. I thought the solution is the number of options that exists when throwing 10 different-color game cubes, minus the number of options in cases not all the digits are found, such as (1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5) or (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1).

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: why does a color matter?

Comment: @Alex Because the throw $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4$ is to be considered different from the throw $1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6$. Far from every combinatorics problem is clear on whether this is the case or not, and specifying that the dice all have different colours is one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  If you search the site you will find many applications.  We start with the $6^{10}$ possible rolls and subtract all the ones that are missing a number.  How many is that?  There are $6$ ways to select the missing number and $5^{10}$ ways to choose the numbers you do get.  Unfortunately, we have subtracted the ones missing two numbers twice each, so we need to add them back in once.  That is ${6 \choose 2}$ ways to choose the missing numbers and $4^{10}$ to choose the ones you have.  So far we have $6^{10}-{6\choose 1}5^{10}+{6 \choose 2}4^{10}$ and you have to worry about how many times we have counted the throws with only $1,2,3$ different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion. Say a throw has property $k$ if the $k$-face doesn't show up, you want the number of throws with none of the 6 properties.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an overkill if you are beginning with discrete math. But I have answered a [similar one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743602/how-many-random-cards-picks-with-replacement-are-required) before.

The number of options $a(k,m,n)$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
  a(k,m,n) = \binom{k}{m}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{m} (-1)^i \, \binom{m}{i}\cdot (m-i)^n
\end{align*}
where

$k$: no. of different faces on a die

$m$: exactly this no. of faces are shown up

$n$: no. of different colored dice are thrown

For your question, $k=6, m=6, n=10$, and hence:

$$a(6,6,10) = 16435440$$